# Making the free Microsoft Virtual Hard Disk image work with VirtualBox's simulated network card

Tags: mac, virtualbox, microsoft-virtual-pc, vhd

I have a Macbook Pro at work and installed the current VirtualBox (3.2.4) today.

However, after using [the free VHD image of IE 7 on XP SP3 from Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=21eabb90-958f-4b64-b5f1-73d0a413c8ef&displaylang=en), the Virtual Operating System (XP) just thought there is no network card provided by the PC (the virtual PC simulated by VirtualBox), even if I set up 4 network cards in Settings, as NAT, host only, etc.

So the XP cannot browse any webpage at all.

Tried VM Fusion (trial version) but it wants `.vmdk` so can't use `.vhd`

Parallels (trial version) can import a VirtualBox machine but can't set up a virtual machine using a .vhd file. I don't know how to do it.

Is there any integration package for VirtualBox to make it work and how?

Is VirtualBox providing a "too advanced" network card so XP SP3 doesn't have the driver for it?

Answer (score 2):

Did you install the VirtualBox Guest Extensions? That way, it should install the network card you've configured under the VM's settings.

To do that, click on the `Devices` menu on VirtualBox, and click `Install Guest Additions`. Apparently, `Host + D` also works. You may need to create a virtual CD-ROM drive for the VM.

As a matter of interest, I've successfully managed to port a Windows XP Mode* VM from Windows 7 to VirtualBox (under OS X), so I don't think it's the XP VM, *per se*.

*[I did have to do an in-place upgrade to remedy the licence issue, but that is secondary to the problem described here]

Answer (score 0):

VMWare offers a converter called [VMware Converter](http://www.vmware.com/products/converter/)

Comment: This converter is free.

Answer (score 0):

For a universal solution you could use disk cloning software within your Virtual PC to dump the disk image in a more universal format. You could then create a new VM in whichever software you prefer and clone the disk image back over from within the new VM.